Is it possible to take questions directly from the area 51 site?
I've noticed quite a few questions whose gists are extremely similar to example questions suggested during the definition phase.  Some have been closed and downvoted, others have gone on to become some of the top questions on this site.

Exhibit A taken from this Area 51 question [closed]
Exhibit B [a very successful question]

Is it acceptable to copy questions from the area 51 site like this and post them here?

The example questions proposed on Area 51 are supposed to be questions you would ask on the actual site. Now the site is here, so if you have a question, ask it. I'm not entirely certain why someone might object if the question was inspired by Area 51.
The problem with the specific question you cited is that it is vague and incomplete. They just copied the title of a question without any actual content. It doesn't represent a real problem… which is why I resist suggestions that we automatically post the top questions from Area 51 when the site is launched. They're not real questions.
